# Save XML generated using DB2 for i into ASCII file

Tags: xml, db2, ascii, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to write RPGLE that would generate an XML using SQL and save it to IFS. The problem I am running into is that when copying XML from IFS using a network share, the XML is not automatically translated from EBCDIC to ASCII. I have tried creating the file first with correct CCSID, but that seemed to get ignored. Only way I was able to overcome this is to use `CPY` and translate while coping. I am just hoping there is a cleaner way.

```
 File_Out_FO   = SQFOVR;
 File_Out_NAME = '/ifs/path/test.xml';
 File_Out_NL   = %Len(%TrimR(File_Out_NAME));
 EXEC SQL
   WITH
     elements AS (
         SELECT
          XMLELEMENT(NAME "element",
           XMLFOREST(
            field1 AS "field1",
            field2 AS "field2",
            field3 AS "field3"
           )
          ) AS element
         FROM table1
     )
     SELECT
      XMLSERIALIZE(
       XMLDOCUMENT(
        XMLELEMENT(NAME "document",
         XMLELEMENT(NAME "elements",
          XMLAGG(elements.element)
         )
        )
       ) AS CLOB  INCLUDING XMLDECLARATION
      ) AS response
     INTO :File_Out
     FROM elements  ;
```

Comment: Why would you expect ASCII? I don't see any CCSID specified for the XML. (I'm not expert at XML to a streamfile.)

Comment: I am not expecting ASCII - I need it. I posted the code just as a starting point. As far as me trying to create the file with a different CCSID, that was out of desperation.

Comment: (Again not as a XML expert)... Two parts to streamfiles: (1) The CCSID attribute of the file, and (2) the CCSID of data written into the file. In nearly all cases, the two should match. You create it as some ASCII type, so I'd think XMLSERIALIZE ... CCSID <ccsid> to match would be appropriate. At least it should be tried. In some processes, you can expect automatic conversion of encodings; I don't know if it happens in your process. Regardless, explicit declarations are usually best when you know what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data in ASCII add CCSID 1208 (819 is not possible) in the XmlSerialize function and make sure that the ifs-file doesn't exist. Otherwise it would keep the file CCSID

```
  XMLSERIALIZE(
   XMLDOCUMENT(
    XMLELEMENT(NAME "document",
     XMLELEMENT(NAME "elements",
      XMLAGG(elements.element)
     )
    )
   ) AS CLOB CCSID 1208 INCLUDING XMLDECLARATION
  ) AS Response
```

And make sure that your machine QCCSID is set to something other than 65535 (that's always causing lots of Problems with conversion aka not converting automatically).

Comment: This worked despite having QCCSID set to 65535. Unfortunately I don't have the authority to change that. Thank you

Comment: The QCCSID setting shouldn't affect this, but it's a good example of what I commented above. The QCCSID value 65535 should not be set for any system that expects to transfer data **reliably**, incoming or outgoing, across network interfaces. It works, often correctly. But you'll never be sure without essentially verifying each byte after the transfer completes every time.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the file with windows codepage

```
  // C Language IFS Prototypes

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // createTempSTMF():  Creates a file name for a temporary stream file
  //
  //   filename = (input) path to file in the IFS
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 DcreateTempSTMF   PR              *   extproc('_C_IFS_tmpnam')
 D string                        39A   options(*omit)

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // removeSTMF():  Deletes the defined streamed file.
  //
  //   filename = (input) path to file in the IFS
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 DremoveSTMF       PR            10I 0 extproc('_C_IFS_remove')
 D filename                        *   VALUE OPTIONS( *String)

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // openSTMF():  Open File for buffered reading/writing
  //
  //   filename = (input) path to file in the IFS
  //       mode = (input) various open mode flags.  (see manual)
  //
  //  returns *NULL upon error, or a pointer to a FILE structure
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 dopenSTMF         PR                  extproc('_C_IFS_fopen')
 d                                     like(pFILE)
 d filename                        *   value options(*string)
 d mode                            *   value options(*string)

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // closeSTMF(): Close File
  //    stream = (input) pointer to FILE structure to close
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 dcloseSTMF        PR            10i 0 extproc('_C_IFS_fclose')
 dparStream                            like(pFILE) value

 dpFile            s               *   based(prototype_only)
 d fd              s                   like(openSTMF)


    //Unique filename in /tmp
    tempFileName = %trim(%str(createTempSTMF(*omit)));

    // create new output file
    fd = openSTMF(%trim(tempFileName): 'w codepage=1252');
    if (fd = *NULL);
       *INLR = *ON;
       return;
    endif;
```

Then you reopen it with text mode so the translation occurs automatically

```
    // ------------------------------------------
    // close file & reopen in text mode so that
    // data will be automatically translated
    // ------------------------------------------
    closeSTMF(fd);
    fd = openSTMF( %trim(tempFileName) : 'a codepage=37');
    if (fd = *NULL);
       *INLR = *ON;
       return;
    endif;
```

Then write some data

```
     //Write some data
     fputsSTMF('Some data': fd);
```